# Migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio Error Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

I've seen many mentions of this problem but most say it happens intermitently.  For me I cannot compile or run my app at all.  There is a build error and it is always there.
I have also seen stack exchange questions stating it is due to the Gradle version and it just needs to be updated in the build.gradle file.  I am already using a far newer version than most of those questions.
It seems to be an error caused by my resource files including all my drawables, and strings.

Note this project runs fine in Eclipse, I have it working on hardware.  When I import it to Studio I get errors.

I have tried the following.
-Restarting Studio
-Clean Project then Rebuild
-Moving resource files to everywhere else in file system within project

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:compileDebugSources]
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
Error:Content is not allowed in prolog.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
C:\Users\jezell\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\DefenderHud\app\src\main\res\drawable_hdpi\app_setup.png
Error:Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\jezell\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\DefenderHud\app\src\main\res\drawable_hdpi\app_setup.png:0:0: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2 mins 37.404 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Did you try renaming the `drawable_hdpi` directory to `drawable-hdpi` etc.?

Comment: my drawable directories were originally named with dash characters when they came from eclipse but it gave me an error saying dash is an illegal character which is why I switched everything to an underscore.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues using a dash. You could try to manually rename the directories outside of Android Studio, e.g., using a file browser. Can you confirm that the `app_setup.png` file is intact?

Comment: When I first imported the project I got the following error so i switched to underscores :Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\jezell\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\vert_line_test.PNG: Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])

Comment: According to this error message you probably should have changed the file names from `v‌​ert_line_test.PNG` to `v‌​ert_line_test.png` etc. Did you try renaming the directories back to use dashes? Can you confirm that the app_setup.png file is intact?

Comment: Now i'm mad at myself it was the uppercase file extensions.  I had to go through and change all the extensions to lower case.  Now I had a successful build.  I was able to leave the dashes in the folder names as well.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem was to rename all incorrectly named files, in detail uppercase letters to lowercase (e.g., `​vert_line_test.PNG` to `vert_line_test.png`) etc.